# How to get year of a movie or TV Show from IMDB

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Is any one tell me how to get a year of specific movie or TV show from IMDB in php?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Comment: Please take the [Stack Overflow tour](/tour) to learn how to write better quality questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OMDB ABI](http://www.omdbapi.com/) might be of help in this instance. All you would need to do is send an HTTP request (including the a movie's title to the service). Assuming a match, you will get back a JSON-formatted string containing the movie in question's year.

For example:

Request:

> http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Batman&y=&plot=short&r=json

Response:

> {"Title":"Batman",**"Year":"1989"**,"Rated":"PG-13","Released":"23 Jun 1989","Runtime":"126 min","Genre":"Action, Adventure","Director":"Tim Burton","Writer":"Bob Kane (Batman characters), Sam Hamm (story), Sam Hamm (screenplay), Warren Skaaren (screenplay)","Actors":"Michael Keaton, Jack Nicholson, Kim Basinger, Robert Wuhl","Plot":"The Dark Knight of Gotham City begins his war on crime with his first major enemy being the clownishly homicidal Joker.","Language":"English, French","Country":"USA, UK","Awards":"Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 21 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"66","imdbRating":"7.6","imdbVotes":"235,641","imdbID":"tt0096895","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}

You could use CURL to get this data:

```
$service_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/';
   $curl = curl_init($service_url);
   $curl_post_data = array(
        "t" => 'batman',
        );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind switching languages, there is also a Python IMDB search package called [imdbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/).

In my experience, OMDB is great if you need to make a few quick queries and will always have access to the Internet.

On the other hand, IMDBPY allows you to create a local version of the IMDB data set (in XML or as a SQL DB). This is more suitable for large operations (such as creating a local movie search platform).

Comment: can you give me an example using simple dom html for php how to get year from the above api.

Comment: well it partially helped me alot.